# Having trouble understanding one line of CSS

Tags: html, css

I was trying to write a chrome extension that blocks all videos from showing in the youtube home page.
I have used the 'view page source' option in chrome browser to obtain the html of the youtube site,and upon inspecting the source,I've concluded that each video is encaplsulated in a div with class 'rich-grid-media-skeleton'
I have tried applying style `display:none` to each div with a class of 'rich-grid-media-skeleton'

However this does not work,and the videos on the home page are still visible.I've found an extension on github,that's does something similar to what im trying to build,and they have used this specific css command to block all youtube videos on the home page

```
ytd-browse[role="main"][page-subtype="home"] #contents {
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

I do not know what ytd-browse is,I have tried searching for instances of 'ytd-browse'in the source html using IDE,however there are no results.

I cannot find any instances of role or page-subtype in in the source html either,I have no idea how this styling works.

Comment: Use inspect element and search for `[role="main"]`; there's one element and adding `display:none;` works to hide all videos.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS rule you posted is matching an element with id "contents" inside a `ytd-browse` element whose `role` attribute is set to "main" and whose `page-subtype` attribute set to "home".

`ytd-browse` is a custom [web component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_(library)), YouTube uses Google's [Polymer library](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer) to implement its web components:

> Polymer is used by a number of Google services and websites, including the YouTube, YouTube Gaming[...]

You can see this custom element when inspecting the source of youtube.com:

[image: developer console showing custom element]

Confusingly, it appears "ytd-browse" is also used as a class name elsewhere on the page (though we know the CSS rule is matching the element because it does not use the `.ytd-browse` class selector):

[image: developer console showing elements with same class name]

Answer (score 0):

Look more carefully at the page source. A quick way to inspect code, press Ctrl + Shift + C (in a Chrome-based browser) and select an element on the page you want to inspect.

Here is the element in question, it's one of the wrappers on the main content page:

```
<ytd-browse class="style-scope ytd-page-manager" responsive-playlist="" page-subtype="home" rich-grid-watch-status="inactive" role="main" guide-persistent-and-visible="">
```